# token value not show in webform submission page

Tags: webforms

I put following submission message in my webform

> Your applicantion id is %value[application_id] 
>   your ip is %ip_address

when submitting the form, the token values didn't showup in submission message. The submission message just shown the same as

> Your applicantion id is %value[application_id] 
>   your ip is %ip_address

Comment: which webform version using?